# Flot pie + bar charts on the same canvas

Tags: flot, bar-chart, pie-chart

Does anyone of you know how to place a pie chart next to a bar chart using flot? I would like them to use the same data.

I tried to enable showing pie in series options, but then the bar chart is blank.

```
$.plot("#placeholder", data, {
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        barWidth: 0.2,
                    },
                    stack: null,
                    pie: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    tickFormatter: plnFormatter
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 0,
                    autoscaleMargin: 0.1
                },
                grid: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true
                }                     
            });
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  What is `data` defined as?  What is `p1nFormatter`?  Provide the smallest example that creates your problem, this is the proper way to ask questions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52cKB/1/

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same question, finally I put a div over the canvas, note the css style:

```html
<div id="error-pie-chart" style="height:120px;width:120px;position: absolute;left:230px;top:50px;z-index:1;"></div>
```

and then use flot to draw the pie on this div, it works!